# Visual Studio cmd doesn't display Unicode characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd, unicode, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to make an ASCII converter in C++ that outputs an image using `▀ ▄ ░ █` Unicode characters.

It works, except for the output part. Instead of the actual characters, it just displays `?`.

When I add `system("chcp 65001");` or `system("chcp 65001");` (to use UTF-8/UTF-16) at the beginning of the file, it doesn't do anything, and still displays `?`

[image]

When I try add `/source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8` to the debug properties, it writes some weird LoLs:

[image]

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define STBI_ONLY_BMP
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    system("chcp 65001");
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char* img = stbi_load("C:/Users/user/source/repos/OCBitmapConvert/grayscale.bmp", &width, &height, &channels, 1);
    if (img == NULL) {
        printf("Error in loading the image\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char imgarray[80][50];
    printf("Loaded image with a width of %dpx, a height of %dpx and %d channels\n", width, height, channels);
    //Convert the image from 1 dimensional array to 2 dimensional array
    for(int y = 0; y < 50; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < 79; x++){
            int pixell = (y*80)+x;
            if(img[pixell] == 0){
                imgarray[x][y] = 0;
            }
            else imgarray[x][y] = 1;
        };
    };
    //Print the 2dim array (just for debugging that the 2d array conversion works correctly)
    for(int y = 0; y < 50; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 79; x++){
            printf("%d",imgarray[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //Convert the image to ascii characters (using ▀ ▄ ░ █). 2 pixels above each other is 1 unicode character
    printf("\n\n\n");
    for(int y = 0; y < 48; y= y+2){
        for(int x = 0; x < 79; x++){
            if(imgarray[x][y] == 0){
                if(imgarray[x][y + 1] == 0){
                    printf("░");
                }
                else printf("▄");
            }
            else{
                if(imgarray[x][y + 1] == 0){
                    printf("▀");
                }
                else printf("█");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: did you store the source file as UTF-8?

Comment: @phuclv there is no source file, there is only .bmp bitmap. It generates the output on the fly. It printfs the unicode file depending on what is in the bitmap

Comment: obviously there must always be at least a source file, which is the cpp file you write above. It needs to be in the correct encoding

Comment: @phuclv Its set to UTF-8

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We don't have "stb_image.h", and we don't need it to see a few Unicode characters printed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. well minimal code is just `system("chcp 65001); printf("unicode character");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, the following code can output ▀ ▄ ░ █ , you could refer to my code to modify your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"░▒▓▄▀█▀ ▄ ░ █\n");
    return 0; // CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YAE U+0518
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

I modified the code with reference to your sample, the code can still run, I suggest you refer to this code and modify it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#define STBI_ONLY_BMP
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    char imgarray[80][50];
    for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 79; x++) {
            
            
             imgarray[x][y] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < 48; y = y + 2) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 79; x++) {
            if (imgarray[x][y] == 1)
                wprintf(L"░▒▓▄▀█▀ ▄ ░ █\n");
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Result:

[image]

In this case you need to find the place that caused the exception. The debugger cannot predict the future, but you can tell it to break on all exceptions, (ctrl+atl+e and tick all the boxes under "Thrown"). When the assert happens walk down the call stack to your code it will tell you which line is causing the problem.

Comment: When executing the setmode line in my code, i get Debug assertion failed error https://imgur.com/a/saj7k4w

Comment: @T0biasCZe   Hi, I updataed my answer,please check it.

Comment: I found out that the app crashed when there was even just a one normal printf. Replaced everything with wprintf (and not just the ones i need unicode in) and now it works